# Counterexample to $\int \left(\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} f_k\right) d\mu = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} \int f_k d {\mu}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I search for a counterexample for the statement

$\int \left(\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} f_k\right) d\mu = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} \int f_k d {\mu}$,
$f_k:X\to [-\infty, \infty]$ for all $k \in N$,
$\sum_\limits{k \in N}|f_k(x)|<\infty$ for all $x \in X$,
where $\mu $ is a measure.

Comment: Standard counterexample: let the graph of $g_k$ be an isosceles triangle with base $[0,1/k]$ and height $2k$, and let $f_1 = g_1$, and for $n > 1$ let $f_k = g_k - g_{k-1}$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k = g_n$. Check that $g_n \to 0$ everywhere but $\int g_n = 1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

My standard example is similar to the one in the comments, but uses rectangles instead of triangles. Define $g_k=k*I_{\left(0,\frac{1}{k}\right)}$, $f_1=g_1$, $f_n=g_n-g_{n-1}$ for $n>1$. The rest is the same.